# gzip error in python: FIle name too long

Tags: python

I am trying to do a zcat of multiple files (15-30) using `subprocess.call` and I am getting an error message of

> Filename too long

I tried to use `shell=True` as suggested in other posts but am still getting the same error. Here is the command I am using:

```
subprocess.call(['zcat','zcat_r1_files'],stdout=f2)
```

here zcat-r1-files are the 15 files (example /path/to/the/directory/containing/the/samples/ABCDEFGHIJK_L001_R1.fastq.gz)

How could I fix it?

Comment: Are all the filenames concatenated as one string, or separate elements of the list?  It is not clear from your post, make sure they are separate elements, it could be taking all your filenames as one huge name (with spaces).

Comment: Can you use [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) with the cwd parameter and then drop the path from your file names?